# Different open graph meta for Facebook like buttons in one page

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I'm developing a page for a restaurant in Wordpress. On the menu page, I need Like buttons for each items in the menu (the items are posts but there is no single page for them). How can I add the Like button (in the loop) to be able to add different image and a title to the og for every menu item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case if someone meets this problem:
If you don't have single.php the wordpress uses index.php. In the header you check if is_single() and than you can create the og meta tags.

Comment: Congrats on figuring this one out!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' (using the green checkmark) so that others in the community can learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

You cannot! You should have separate page (with unique URL) for every item (which will be represented as Open Graph object) you want to use Like Button for.